# Unity game fails to compile in Xcode: clang: error: no such file or directory:il2cpp_output/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.cpp

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, clang

I am trying to build my iOS Unity game at Xcode (Unity -> Build and Run). Unity completes building, but on Xcode, it fails when compiling:

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/Can/Documents/Programming/Unity/MyGame/MyGame-iOS/il2cpp_output/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.cpp'
clang: error: no input files
```

How can I solve this? I am on Unity 5.1.3f and Xcode 6.4, OS X Yosemite 10.10.5.